# Flutter format DateTime

Tags: android, flutter, datetime, dart

I am creating a form in flutter where one of the fields is a date of birth. I have used a DateTime picker to pick the date and show the output. I would like to format the date I get to only show month, date,and year. Here is the date format currently `YYYY-MM-JJ  HH-MM:00.000`. I would like it to be in this format `MM-dd-yyy`.
This is the code I came up with

```
---
DateTime _dateTime;
---
Text(
              _dateTime == null
                  ? 'Nothing has been picked yet'
                  : _dateTime.toString(),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: _dateTime == null ? DateTime.now() : _dateTime,
                  firstDate: DateTime(1930),
                  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                ).then((date) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dateTime = date;
                    
                  });
                });
              },
              child: Text('Pick a date'),
            )
```

Comment: Use [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date format from flutter

```
final f = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
f.format(date);
```

You can replace `yyyy-MM...` To whatever you like

Answer (score 0):

Add the package intl

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

And call the class DateFormate()

```
DateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(_dateTime);
```